# Combine Observable with ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my project I want to call an api using Observables and then with the power of ReplaySubject, I want to remember the results of it so when I revisit that page, I don't have to call the api again. Ideally I remember the results for a set number of milliseconds which I know you can set in ReplaySubject.

One of the problems I'm aware of is the subscription can't be on the component because it will just restart when you revisit the page again, therefore a service file would need to be used.

To start with I have my normal **http.service** file which should be fine as it is:

**http.service.ts**

```
getVenuesListViaPost(filter, searchObj): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post("api/venues/search"+filter, searchObj)
}
```

Then I have my component which actually shows the data. This should be fine as it is.

**venues.component.ts**

```
getData(page: number) {
        this.listedAsyncData$ = this.replayApiService.replayVenueApi(page, this.name);
 }
```

I'm using the async pipe on my component ie:

**venues.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (listedAsyncData$ | async)?.items"><td>{{item.name}}</td></tr>
```

So I think the problem lies with my replayApiService but I'm confused as to why this doesn't do anything.

**replay-api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from "./http.service";
import {ReplaySubject, tap} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ReplayApiService {

    private _rememberSource = new ReplaySubject<object>(1, 200000);
    remember$ = this._rememberSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }


    replayVenueApi(page, name) {
        this.httpService.getVenuesListViaPost(`?pageno=${page}&pageSize=10`, { name }).pipe(
          tap(res => this._rememberSource.next({
            "items": res.body,
            "totalPages": parseInt(res.headers.get('x-paging-pagecount'))
          }))
        ).subscribe();
      }

}
```

I can see the network call is made correctly, however the results don't show on the page.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `async` pipe when it is the accepted best practice?

Comment: It looks like you're making an infinite loop with `this._rememberSource.next(myObj);`

Comment: @WillAlexander because there are circumstances where I can't use it. I need to slightly alter the results after I receive them from the api and the scope of it is too much to do inside an rxjs pipe.

Comment: You don't need to subscribe to `remember$` to make it emit with `next`. Why not just call `this._rememberSource.next(myObj)` in your subscribe callback?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward there's nothing you can't do inside an RxJS pipe. If it's a lot of lines, all you need to do is create a named method which you call from within the pipe. Assigning an Observable emission to a local variable is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @WillAlexander ok I've changed to async and have updated my answer but I have the same problem. Regarding your comment for "You don't need to subscribe to remember$", please could you put that into an answer for me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you refactor `replayVenueApi` as follows:

```js
replayVenueApi(page, name) {
  this.httpService.getVenuesListViaPost(`?pageno=${page}&pageSize=10`, { name }).pipe(
    tap(res => this._rememberSource.next({
      "items": res.body,
      "totalPages": parseInt(res.headers.get('x-paging-pagecount'))
    }))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

This doesn't implement your "don't repeat request if it has been less than 20s", but it does mean that your ReplaySubject will emit.

In your component, you need to use the Observable, because `replayVenuApi` doesn't return anything:

```js
getData(page: number) {
  this.listedAsyncData$ = this.replayApiService.remember$;
  this.replayApiService.replayVenueApi(page, this.name);
}
```

For the timer element, one possible approach is to store a timestamp and compare it to the `Date.now()` of each call to `replayVenueApi()`.  If the difference is less than 20 seconds, you do nothing. If it's more, you make the request.

Comment: Thanks very helpful! I can see the page loads quicker now when revisiting it, however I can see an api call still being made since we are calling this.replayApiService.replayVenueApi everytime we revisit. Any way I can prevent that?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer suggests an approach.

Comment: Cool thanks for your answer :) Thought I might have been able to escape writing logic for the time thing. The more I think about it, it might be more elegant to deal with this with interceptors and store time logic in a central object in a service file to remember results and there timestamp. Otherwise I'll need to acquire data from different resource depending on if I want to remember them or not. Still though, thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you look into a library like NgRx or Ngxs. State management libraries are optimised and work better than anything you or I can put together ^^

Comment: I know my brain though has problems getting to grips with ngxs. I can understand rxjs a lot easier so I was wanting to use it some more than resorting to ngxs.

Comment: If you wind up using a redux library, I recommend NgRx over Ngxs. Steeper learning curve, but much more precise control over everything.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I saw in a reddit group people were switching angular to pwa mode using service workers. Is that a viable option do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242844/discussion-between-will-alexander-and-andrew-junior-howard).